# Combobox selection based on FindStringExact not working as intended

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, combobox, sorteddictionary

I'm trying to select the item in the Combobox based on the stored value in a `Sorteddictionary`

*String value matching*

```
  comboBoxEdit3.SelectedItem = comboBoxEdit3.FindStringExact(Queries[_ucSetting.StandardSearchID.ToString()] + "(" + _ucSetting.StandardSearchID.ToString() + ")");
```

[image]

*Elements in ComboBox*

[image]

But this produces empty selection in the ComboBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FindStringExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstringexact?view=netframework-4.8) only returns the index of the *first* item that matches your string, or -1 if no match is found. You're trying to set the *SelectedItem* to the index being returned. You should set the *SelectedIndex* instead:

```
comboBoxEdit3.SelectedIndex = comboBoxEdit3.FindStringExact(Queries[_ucSetting.StandardSearchID.ToString()] + "(" + _ucSetting.StandardSearchID.ToString() + ")");
```